# Test class Limits.getEmailInvocations() showing zero and assertion is failing

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, singleemailmessage, send-email

I have a bizarre issue. I have a trigger that will send an email based upon a record update. When I debug my trigger running the test class it showing the email result as success and when I debug and Limits.getEmailInvocations() it is correctly showing 1 right after calling sendEmails.

```
System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations()); // Debugs 0
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
System.debug(Limits.getEmailInvocations()); // Debugs 1
```

When running my test method the assertion will fail however:

```
Test.startTest();
update recordsToUpdate;
Test.stopTest();
// This fails
System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
```

I can even see the email activity being created in the log, so not sure why Limits.getEmailInvocations() is asserting wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is because the test.starttest and test.stoptest create a new apex context. Inside the context it will show 1.

so try:

```
Test.startTest();
update recordsToUpdate;
System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations()); // Will show 1
Test.stopTest();
System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations()); // Will fail as no invocations are visible
```

### Edit

New info says that the email is being sent via a future method.

This will definitely cause the first assert above to fail as the future method is not called until `test.stopTest()`. I could see this causing the second assert to fail as well as future methods are called in separate contexts so the second assert would still not know if the email was sent.

One option would be to make sure emails are being saved as activities and to query for the activity. Then you can assert that the activity exists and you'll know your email will be sent.

Another would be to change your service class a little bit:

```
public static void sendEmail(String Message) {
    // All the email stuff
}

// Call non future method from future context
@Future
public static void sendEmailFuture(String message) {
    sendEmail(messsage);
}
```

Then in your test class you can test a few things:

```
@isTest
public static void sendEmailTest() {
    Service.sendEmail('Message'); // Call non future method
    System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations()); // verify email
}

@isTest
public static void sendEmailFutureTest() {
    Test.startTest();
    sendEmailFuture('Message');
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, Limits.getFutureCalls()); // Verify the future method was fired
}
```

This pattern is more versatile and can be used for other, non email tests where querying for the activity may not be an option.

Comment: Still fails for some reason.

Comment: If emails are not sent in test context, am not sure Limits.getEmailInvocations() will ever return value.

Comment: @AndrewL. What Pranay said. If it is still showing 0, that means that your trigger is not actually sending an email. You may need to debug your code.

Comment: @gNerb The last line should compare to 0 to demonstrate that it passes.

Comment: I think the problem may be is that the trigger is calling a future method. The future method is being called and tested in the test class and it debugs the correct values, but maybe the test context is incorrect. Not sure really.

Comment: So the email is being sent from a future method? That would definitely cause at least some confusion as future methods are called from their own context as well. The assert inside the test class would fail because the email is sent after the test finishes and the assert outside the test could fail because the email is sent in a seperate context before it is called. My only other advise would be to make sure "saveasactivity" is true and then check for the activity being created.

Comment: @gNerb Yes, that's what I changed the assertion to. The test class verifies an email activity has been created for each record I am updating that meets the criteria. When I perform the query after stop test I see that I am getting the correct number of results.

Comment: Andrew, take 1 more look at my answer as it does have another option for you as well. Just something to think about. If this answer works for you, please make sure to accept it.

Comment: @AndrewL. - an [apexmocks alternative](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/23/apexmocks-and-email/) which I use all the time when verifying emails