# How to retrieve second set of email invocations in unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, singleemailmessage

[image]

I'm triggering an apex email in my unit test. I would like to assert that 1 email has been invoked. I can see from the logs that it is invoked. However, it seems that my code is looking at the wrong limit results.

I have tried running the test class both synchronusly and a-synchronisly but it fails either way. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your attempt?  Maybe try declaring an Integer and assigning it to     Limits.getEmailInvocations() and use that in your assert statement.  Does your test send email async or synchronously?  That information will guide where your assertion must go relative to any starttest / stoptest calls.  See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252796/test-class-limits-getemailinvocations-showing-zero-and-assertion-is-failing for more info.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for the helpful reply. The link you added answered my question. I just needed to move the Limits.getEmailInvocations() call inside the start stop test brackets. If you want to add this as an answer I can mark is as solved. Many thanks again